# Rails associations between clients and sellers - has_many :through or has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many-through

I'm beginning a project with rails where there are **products**, **clients** and **sellers**. Each seller `has_many products`. Each Client `has_many products`. (And in my case, each client only buys one product at a time).

I want to know who are my clients' seller and my Seller's clients, knowing that, they'll be linked by, the purchase, of one product.

Should I use a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association between clients and sellers ? Or a double `has_many through :products`, like :

**Seller** :

```
has_many :clients through :products

Belongs_to :products
```

**Client** :

```
has_many :sellers through :products

Belongs_to :products
```

In order to avoid two `belongs_to` in the `product` class, could this work ?

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :products, as: :productable

has_many :sellers, through: :products

end

class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :products, as: :productable

has_many :clients, through: :products

end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :productable, polymorphic: true

end
```

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: First, it should be `has_and_belongs_to_many :products` in both these models, and in Product. Since it is many-to-many relationship b/w Client-Products, Sellers-Products.

Comment: Well in fact, each product is unique. It's like they are paintings, and the sellers are painters. Each painter can make/create many paintings, but a painting only has one painter, and will only have one client. But a client can buy many paintings from a painter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with **`has_many :through`** here.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :products

has_many :sellers, through: :products

end

class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :prodcuts

has_many :clients, through: :products

end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :client
belongs_to :seller

end
```

> The simplest rule of thumb is that you should set up a has_many
>   :through relationship if you need to work with the relationship model
>   as an independent entity. If you don't need to do anything with the
>   relationship model, it may be simpler to set up a
>   has_and_belongs_to_many relationship (though you'll need to remember
>   to create the joining table in the database).
>
> You should use has_many :through if you need validations, callbacks,
>   or extra attributes on the join model.

And also see these **[Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many)** for choosing between **`HABTM`** and a **`has_many :through`**

Comment: I would **always** recommend `has_many :through` rather than habtm.  It allows you to populate the join model with extra information, which will often be required further down the line.

Comment: Thank you very much. Beside it, I was wondering if it isn't bether to avoid the two belongs_to in the product class, and to use polymorphic associations.

Comment: @Francky Yes,it seems fine with `Polymorphic`.But be careful when using.It is a tricky one to handle.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Agreed! I prefer the same too :)

Comment: @Francky And finally don't forget to accept my answer if you think it really helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

I want to approach your question from the other end: let us start from the product. I think this will clarify a lot of things.

So you have three models: `Seller, Client` and `Product`.

A `Product` has a seller and client. In your model that would like this:

```
class Product
  belongs_to :seller
  belongs_to :client
end
```

This means that in the products table we have a column `seller_id` and `client_id`.

Afaik a product needs to have both, always. So this also means you *cannot* use a polymorphic association here. At least not the way you proposed it. If you write

```
 belongs_to :productable, polymorphic: true
```

you will add the fields `productable_id` and productable_type`to your`Product` model. But that is only *1* link (so either a seller or a client, but never both). You could introduce a link table here, so a product could be linked to many "productables" but in your case i think it is besides the point. You know a product has one seller and one client.

Secondly, now this is established, your `Product` is exactly the link-table between clients and sellers. So you do not have to introduce a new link-table, just use the one already there.

```
class Seller
  has_many :products
  has_many :clients, through: :products
end

class Client
  has_many :products
  has_many :sellers, through: :products
end
```

So in conclusion:

- use the `has_many :through` because you already have the link table as a model. Only use a habtm if you do not care about the join-table (link-table).
- you can't use a polymorphic association here, as you need two links (without introducing a link-table, which seems overkill imho). I like the explicitness, clarity, readability of having an explicit `seller_id` and `client_id`, and it is also easier to manage.